# Wrong parsing when importing csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm, pandas-datareader

I am trying to import a csv format file. this is tick trading data info. The file is as follows:

```
0,2017-09-18 02:00:06,12568.00,1,201,12567.00,12568.00,5462,0,0,C,
0,2017-09-18 02:00:06,12568.50,2,203,12567.00,12568.00,5463,0,0,C,
0,2017-09-18 02:00:06,12569.00,1,204,12567.00,12569.00,5468,0,0,C,
0,2017-09-18 02:00:06,12569.00,1,205,12567.00,12569.00,5470,0,0,C,
0,2017-09-18 02:00:06,12569.50,3,208,12567.00,12569.00,5471,0,0,C,
```

I am using this python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("XG#/20170918.txt", names=['empty', 'date time', 'last', 'last size', 'bid', 'ask'])
print(df.head(1))
```

my output is this:

> ```
>                 empty  date time  last  \ 0 2017-09-18 02:00:06 12567.0 200.0 200.0 12567.0  12567.0     5430.0   0.0   
>
>                                                last size bid  ask   0 2017-09-18 02:00:06 12567.0 200.0 200.0 12567.0        0.0   C  NaN
> ```
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

My questions are:

1. Why my "names" (headers) are not starting on the first column?
2. How do I make 2nd column as date-time and index?
3. How do I widen the result so I will see all the data in one line (I am using pycharm)? since I need to make date-time as index, I need to remove column 0 but when using `df.drop(df.index[0])` nothing happens.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can you please paste your data properly? Or is all your data in a single line to begin with?

Comment: this is all the code i am using. csv file is big and i added here only first few lines

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it hasn't been pasted properly. I can't see individual lines separated.

Comment: Try this: `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and paste it in your question please.

Comment: Actually, more importantly, please open your CSV file in a text editor and paste the first 5 lines exactly as it is in your question.

Comment: C:\Users\gilad\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/gilad/PycharmProjects/Sendex/Importing IqFeed Tick data.py"
{'empty': {(0, '2017-09-18 02:00:06', 12567.0, 200.0, 200.0, 12567.0): 12567.0, (0, '2017-09-18 02:00:06', 12568.0, 1.0, 201.0, 12567.0): 12568.0, (0, '2017-09-18 02:00:06', 12568.5, 2.0, 203.0, 12567.0): 12568.0, (0, '2017-09-18 02:00:06', 12569.0, 1.0, 204.0, 12567.0): 12569.0, (0, '2017-09-18 02:00:06', 12569.0, 1.0, 205.0, 12567.0): nan}}

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: In your question please, I can't see newlines in the comments.

Comment: Each row has to be delimited by a newline. That is how a table is created, yes? I need to see where the row ends and the next one begins :(

Comment: Please edit your question with the requested information. Thank you :)

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 10 columns and you have names for 6 columns, so this how the code should look like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('lol.csv',usecols = list(range(0,6)),names=['empty', 'date_time', 'last', 'last_size', 'bid', 'ask'])
```

i used the first 6 columns, please feel to understand the below example and name your desired columns.

> **usecols** is where you put a **list** of your column numbers which you want it to be **named**.

**for eg** : if you want col 1,3,4 to be named as name,gender,address then the code will look like

```
pd.read_csv('lol.csv',usecols = [1,3,4],names=['name','gender','address'])
```

> **for the third question**

```
df = pd.read_csv('lol.csv',usecols = list(range(0,6)),names=['empty','date_time', 'last', 'last_size', 'bid', 'ask'],index_col = 'date_time' )
```

you can use the index_col parameter to tell which column to use as index.

> **to drop a column**
>   after you import an csv in variable (for eg: df ) using pandas, use the following code:

```
df.drop('empty', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks! could you pls reffer to my 3rd question as well as df.drop(columns=['empty']) not working for me